# Can I use metaprogramming to generate a different function for every possible parameter value?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I would like reduce the numbers of parameters passed to a function by creating as many functions as possible parameters combination.

Let's say I have a struct with a few registers :

```
struct S {
    std::array<int,5> reg;
};
```

and a function adding some registers together :

```
void add(S& s, int a, int b){
    s.reg[b] += s.reg[a];
}
```

Can I use metaprogramming to generate a different function for every possible parameter value ?

That is :

```
add_0_0(S& s){s.reg[0] += s.reg[0];} // equivalent to add(S& s, 0, 0)
add_0_1(S& s){s.reg[0] += s.reg[1];} // equivalent to add(S& s, 0, 1)
...
add_4_4(S& s){s.reg[4] += s.reg[4];} // equivalent to add(S& s, 4, 4)
```

I could achieve this using a script and some macros, a bit like this :

```
for a in {0..4}
do
for b in {0..4}
do
echo "void add_"$a"_"$b"(S& s)"
echo "{"
echo "    s.reg["$b"] += s.reg["$a"];"
echo "}"
done
done
```

but I thought it could be a good candidate for metaprogramming. Unfortunately I don't know where to start ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, pretty much how template functions work in C++, with the only difference is the actual naming convention used by the "different" functions:

```
template<int a, int b>
void add(S& s){
    s.reg[b] += s.reg[a];
}
```

and then:

```
add<0,0>(s);
add<0,1>(s);
// ...
add<4,4>(s);
```

This is fairly basic use of templates in C++. The naming convention might seem a bit awkward the first time it's seen. But, with practice and experience, it won't be long before it becomes natural, and second-nature.

P.S. There's nothing that immediately stops you from calling

```
add<4,5>(s);
```

and all hell breaking loose. But, with a little bit more work it's possible to produce a compilation error, were that to happen.

Comment: Thank you, I have used templates for types previously, but not that way ... it gives me a good start, and with some work I'll be able to achieve what I want to do.